# Custom SQL using EF Core's fluent API and model builder

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I need check constraints for my entities, and EF Core doesn't support that (I think?). For example:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (1 <= Foo);
```

I can do this in a migration. But in my case I prefer to do it in the configuration instead.

Is that possible? (EF Core has changed so much, it's hard to keep track of all the new stuff.)

Something like

```
modelBuilder
  .Property(b => b.Foo)
  .IsRequired()
  .Custom("ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (1 <= Foo);");
```

Or

```
modelBuilder
  .Custom("ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_SomeTable_SomeColumn CHECK (1 <= Foo);");
```

Or something similar?

Comment: Sounds like feature request for their GitHub repo.

Comment: @IvanStoev So you are not aware of anything like this? I don't want to pollute their repo if something like this already exists.

Comment: There is neither `ModelBuilder` API, nor `MigrationBuilder` method. Which means the only option is `MigrationBuilder.Sql` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah unfortunate. I've filed [a feature request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7957) like you recommended.